# Non injective-morphism between two multigraphs.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I'm trying to find a non injective morphism between two multigraphs, but I couldn't find any. Could someone give an example (if it's possible?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just wondering, do you get some kind of notification bugging you to accept an answer after a few months? I'm always puzzled when someone accepts my answer eons later.

Comment: Nah, I didn't get any notification. He was the only one who answered my question so he deserves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbitrary functions from a multigraph with no edges to any other multigraph are morphisms.